# How many unique words are in the text file and what are the counts of those unique words

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class dictionary {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Read all the words from the dictionary (text.txt) into an array
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
        int bufferLength = 1000000;
        char[] buffer = new char[bufferLength];
        int charsRead = br.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        br.close();
        String text = new String(buffer);
        text = text.trim();
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        String[] words = text.split("\n");

        System.out.println("Total number of words in text: " + words.length);

        //to find for unique text
        String[] uniqueText = {};
        int[] textCount = new int[uniqueText.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

            if (uniqueText[i].contains(words[i])) {
                textCount[i]++;

            } else {
                uniqueText[i] = words[i];

            }

        }
    }
```

Hi i cant figure out my code here and i dont really know how to put my question in words so i'll use a pseudocode instead.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException was achieved on

if (uniqueText[i].contains(words[i]))

> create a string array [uniqueText]
>   create an int array [uniqueTextCount]
>
> ```
>    For every word in text
>
>       if word[i] exists in uniqueText(
>             +uniqueTextCount[i])
>       else(
>            + the new unique word to uniqueText)
> ```

Comment: You're not really asking a question; what do you need help with?

Comment: Are you looking for how many unique words are in the text file and what are the counts of those unique words?

Comment: Could do it with a HashMap, where key is word, and value is the count, and loop: read word, put count of one in map.  If put returns a value, add 1 to it and put the sum back.

Comment: Hello,
Im sorry about that i'm new to stackoverflow and coding. But what im actually asking is how to write the correct code for the pseudocode as i've tried using mine up there

 if (uniqueText[i].contains(words[i])) {
            textCount[i]++;

        } else {
            uniqueText[i] = words[i];
which gives me an error

Comment: BTW, you're assuming one word per line, since you're splitting on "\n"

Comment: @DBug yes i am making the whole text file(which is a document) into one word in an array form.

Comment: "which gives me an error" -- and what might that error be?  You don't mention any error in your question (hint: edit your question to add more detail).

Comment: You're reading in the file into a character buffer and then converting to a string, so at this point, you have a String of characters.  When you split this by "\n", your "words" array will have an array of lines, not single words, unless each word is on a separate line.

Comment: @DBug it is each word on a separate line and i have debug that part and it works. Say in the text file i have (hello, world) in the array text it'll be [0]hello [1], [2]world.

Comment: @Michael hi i am initially looking for how many unique words are in the text file(which is a document of mine) and what are the counts of those unique words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are initializing a blank array, `String[] uniqueText = {};`, and then trying to add to that array (`uniqueText[i] = words[i];`). What I believe you are looking for is something like a `List` where the size can be dynamic since we don't know how many unique words there are from the start. Or we can even take it a step forward and use a `Map` which also has a dynamic size but utilizes a key and value and is perfect for this situation since we want to link the word to the count.

```
System.out.println("Total number of words in text: " + words.length);

Map<String, Integer> uniqueWordsAndCount = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : words) { 
    if (uniqueWordsAndCount.containsKey(word)){ //If word is in our map already, increase count
        uniqueWordsAndCount.put(word, uniqueWordsAndCount.get(word)+1);
    }else{  //If not in our map, add it and set count to 1
        uniqueWordsAndCount.put(word, 1);
    }
} 
//Accessing the count of a word
uniqueWordsAndCount.get("someWord"); //This returns the count
```